# Working with files based on filename calulated from time

Tags: linux, bash, awk, filesystems, raspberry-pi

I have a remote Linux computer, a raspberry pi, that snaps two pictures a minute and uploads them to a Linux server.  The photos are named like this: SITE-03-22-16-091543.jpeg.  With the filename being formatted like: Sitename-month-day-year-hourminutesecond.jepg.  Before the photo is sent, via scp, I embed some local weather date into each photo using exiv2.  That way the weather conditions are stored within each photo. All of that is working fine.  I hope to have about 15 of these all sending back two snaps a minute to the server.

On the server side, these photos are stored within their own SITE folder.  The idea is to make time-lapse videos from each site.  There are four types of time-lapses we are interested in:

1)  A 24 hour loop, from 12:00am to 11:59pm.

2)  A sunrise loop, from 30 minutes before sunrise to 2 hours past sunrise

3)  A sunset loop, from 2 hours before sun set to 30 minutes past sunset

4)  A daylight loop, from 30 minutes before sunrise to 30 minutes past sunset

The 24 hour loop is simple.

The sunrise and sunset loops are a little trickier.  I downloaded and complied the “sunwait” program from Ian Craig on SourceForge (https://sourceforge.net/projects/sunwait4windows/).  Using the command “sunwait list rise 35.1174N 89.9711W | gawk -F: '{ print $1$2 }'” produces the output 0700, sun rise at my location.  And using the 'set' option, produces 1913, sunset at my location.  Since I don't live at the equator, the sunrise and sunset vary from 5:30am to 7:30am. Depending on season.  Of course.

I have the code to compile a list of images into the move, add on overlay, and add the embedded weather data.  The question is how to create a list of the 30 minutes of pictures before the sunrise + 2 hours.  Then 2 hours before sunset + 30 minutes past.  Then finally, 30 minutes before sunrise all the way through sunset + 30 minutes.

I'm sure the answer is MATH!  Can someone start me on the yellow brick road?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

substituting your script to generate time by echo here

```
$ echo 07:10 | 
  awk -F: -v offset=30 -v path="$filepath" '{
                         h=$1-int(offset/60);
                         m=$2-offset%60;
                         if(m<0) {m=m+60; h--}
                         for(i=0;i<=150;i++)
                           {m++;
                            if(m>59) {m=m%60; h++};
                            printf path"%02d%02d.jpeg\n",h,m}}'
```

creates a 151 step counter that starts from offset (in minutes) given hours minutes.  For the other case enter offset as 120.  Assumes start/end times doesn't change the date.  May not be true around North Pole!

I think some of the variables can be simplified, but can be a working base for further improvements.

update: int() was missing, fixed, also you can pass the path as another variable

Comment: Thanks.  It looks that if the sunrise occurs later than half past the hour, say at 06:35, this subtracts 1 hour and 30 minutes.  not 30 minutes.  You are very close.  also, I want to embed the path to the pictures and the site name in the printf command, but it shows this on the output $homediir/site/$sitefilename0821*.jpeg.  Thanks again.  We are close.

Comment: that does fix the time problem.  Can I ask you a few questions, because while the code does what I asked.  I need to add one more thing to it.

Comment: Ask away.  If generic you may want to create a new question to solicit more answers.

Comment: Thanks.  The purpose of the code is to produce a list of files that list all the photos in the SITE folder that were taken 30 minutes before sunrise and 2 hours after.  this code does produce a list of partial possible filenames of those photos.  I added a * to the line " printf path"%02d%02d*.jpeg\n",h,m}}. and output the results to a seperate file called filelist.txt.  A line from that file looks like this: /home/server/webcam/sites/HOME/HOME-03-28-16-0623*.jpeg.  since there are 2 photo per minute

Comment: how can i gather a complete list of all the possible files when I dont know what the remaning 2 digits of the photos for that munute?

Comment: this is a sample of the sites folder
-rw-r--r-- 1 randy randy  246101 Mar 28 10:29 HOME-03-28-16-102913.jpeg

-rw-r--r-- 1 randy randy  224938 Mar 28 10:29 HOME-03-28-16-102944.jpeg

-rw-r--r-- 1 randy randy  225190 Mar 28 10:30 HOME-03-28-16-103012.jpeg

-rw-r--r-- 1 randy randy  224396 Mar 28 10:30 HOME-03-28-16-103043.jpeg

Comment: for example `ls filename??.jpeg`  replace filename with the known part and two question marks indicate two chars in those places.

Comment: yes.  is there a way incorporate the ls command within your code to product the list.  the list of files is what I pass to the mencoder program to create the time-lapse. thanks again. sorry, im not a programmer at heart, just someone asked to make something for a project  thrown together at the last minute.

Comment: add "??" before ".jpeg" in the printf statement.  It will produce the file list with the question marks.  Any bash script will interpret it correctly.  If a program is looking for exact filenames then, you have to create a new list out of this.  For example `ls $(awk ... )` will work.  Or you can save the outcome of the awk to a file (i.e awk ... > filelist), then do `ls $(cat filelist)`.